# Fast iteration over unicode string Cython

Tags: unicode, cython

I have the following cython function.

```
 01: 
+02: cdef int count_char_in_x(unicode x,Py_UCS4  c):
 03:     cdef:
+04:         int count = 0
 05:         Py_UCS4 x_k
 06: 
+07:     for x_k in x: ## Yellow
+08:         if x_k == c:
+09:             count+=1
 10: 
+11:     return count
```

Line 07 is not properly optimized.

The annotated HTML code is expanded as:

```
+07:     for x_k in x: ## Yellow
  if (unlikely(__pyx_v_x == Py_None)) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "'NoneType' is not iterable");
    __PYX_ERR(0, 8, __pyx_L1_error)
  }
  __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_v_x);
  __pyx_t_1 = __pyx_v_x;
  __pyx_t_6 = __Pyx_init_unicode_iteration(__pyx_t_1, (&__pyx_t_3), (&__pyx_t_4), (&__pyx_t_5)); if (unlikely(__pyx_t_6 == ((int)-1))) __PYX_ERR(0, 8, __pyx_L1_error)
  for (__pyx_t_7 = 0; __pyx_t_7 < __pyx_t_3; __pyx_t_7++) {
    __pyx_t_2 = __pyx_t_7;
    __pyx_v_x_k = __Pyx_PyUnicode_READ(__pyx_t_5, __pyx_t_4, __pyx_t_2);
```

- Any tips on how could this be improved?
- I think it is possible to write a cdef/cpdef function that at runtime completly avoids Python None type checks. Any idea on how this could be done?

Comment: Who or what's supposed to handle unicode strings?  'C' was created long before unicode (which uses 1-4 bytes per character); so `cython` has to either implement its own unicode, import some third party library, or use Python's implementation.

Comment: Cython has the capability to use C++ strings, I guess that could be an option.

Answer (score 1):

The generated C code looks pretty good to me. The loop overall is a int-iterated for loop (i.e. it's not relying on calling the Python methods `__iter__` and `__next__`).

`__Pyx_PyUnicode_READ` [is translated pretty directly to `PyUnicode_READ`](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/9c26b302791515f608d4b200f692dcec9f066229/Cython/Utility/ModuleSetupCode.c#L742) (depending slightly on the Python version you're using). `PyUnicode_READ` is a C macro which is [as close to a direct array access as you can get](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/680254a8dc64e3ada00f88a7c42d41eb02108353/Include/cpython/unicodeobject.h#L383).

This is probably as good as it's getting. You might get a small improvement by using `bytes` rather than `unicode` (provided you're dealing with ASCII characters). You might just consider whether it's really worth reimplementing [`unicode.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations).

If it were a regular `def` function you could declare `x` as `unicode not None` to remove the `None` check before the loop. That might make a small difference. However, as @ead points out that isn't supported for `cdef` functions. It's likely the cost of a `def` function call will be slightly larger than the cost of a `None`-check, but you should time it if you care.

Comment: @ead You do remember correctly - I've updated my answer slightly

Comment: Is there any other way to avoid the None check during the loop? Maybe a macro ? Using a `def` function does not pay off (by a large margin). I was trying to use the C++ string/unicode with `c_string type`, but I see no difference. I think it is possible to write a `cdef/cpdef` function that at runtime completly avoids Python `None` type checks but I do not know how to do it.

Comment: I don't know another way of getting rid of the None check. The None check is once, at the start of the loop (definitely not on every iteration). It should ultimately end up as a single pointer comparison, so I wouldn't worry about it too much.